# Domain Name with a-entry to x.xxxxx.com?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis, iis-7, web-server

i ordered a domain (e.g. www.myNewDomain.com).

Now I will redirect the domain www.myNewDomain.com to my Windows ISS 7.0 Server which is sub.MyOldDomain.com.

But in the domain A-entry is only a IP enterable, what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an "A" record, you can use a "CNAME" record.  CNAME records point to an alternate domain and work similarly to A records.  So, going to www.newdomain.com will return a CNAME record of "sub.olddomain.com" along with the A record for that domain.

Answer (score 0):

Direct `www.mynewdomain.com` to the IP address of your IIS server (i.e. of the IP associated with `sub.myolddomain.com`) and then configure an additional site using a "host header" in IIS for `www.mynewdomain.com`. See e.g. [Configure a Host Header for a Web Site (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx)
 for how to do that.

Comment: So in the Bindings enter the IP of the server from www.myolddomain.com and any port I want?
And then http://IP:Port to reach it via internet explorer?

Comment: First, add an A-entry in your DNS server to point `www.mynewdomain.com` to the IP of your server. Then, either create a new web site in IIS or add a binding to an existing one. In the binding, enter the IP of the server, port 80, and `www.mynewdomain.com` as "host name". Then you should be able to reach your site via http://www.mynewdomain.com/ as expected.

Comment: I have allready a Port 80 redirect with a other domain, so the port is blocked.

Comment: The whole point of "host headers" (aka "name-based virtual hosts") is that multiple domains can be hosted using a single port.